# How can I render the “that” in “Don’t be like that”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, expression

I said to one of my German friends who was being pessimistic:

> Sei nicht so es!

He answered that I could not use *es* but that I could add an adjective to it like

> Sei doch nicht so pessimistisch, zum Beispiel.

He could not find a way to just say “don’t be like that” or “ne sois pas comme ça” in German. Any idea?

Comment: "Sei nicht so" could work, depending on circumstances.

Comment: That's the first thing that I thought, after seeing the title, but before visting this page (+1).

Comment: `render` -> `translate`

Comment: Your "es" would mean "das" here. But "Sei nicht wie das" is not good German, and "wie das" is replaced with "so" (="that way").

Answer (score 21):

I do wonder why your friend couldn’t tell you that you already had the perfect translation for ‘Don’t be like that’ — it is:

> Sei nicht so.

*So* is the perfect, idiomatic and complete translation of *like that.* Yes, it may seem weird that two words are translated by one word, but some things just are like that — ‘Manche Dinge sind **so.’** For completeness, here are a few more examples:

> If he carries on **like that,** he’ll never learn.
> S’il continue **comme ça,** il n’apprendra jamais.
> Wenn er **so** weitermacht, lernt er es nie.
>
> Take a look, I’ll show you again. You do it **like that.**
> Voyez, je vous le montre encore une fois. Vous le faites **comme ça.**
> Schauen Sie her, ich zeige es Ihnen nochmal. **So** machen Sie es.
>
> He who drives **like that** must have a guardian angel.
> Celui qui conduit **comme ça** doit avoir un ange gardien.
> Wer **so** fährt, muss einen Schutzengel haben.

I’ve seen Hubert write this phrase in different variants a few times in recent answers and it fits here well: **Remember that you never translate *words* but always *meanings.***

Comment: Suggestions to improve my French are always welcome!

Comment: I suggest that you improve your French :-)

Comment: The same happens on Portuguese with "assim", that directly translates "like that" or "in this specific way". "Don't be like that" -> "Não seja assim".

Comment: The German phrase _Jetzt sei doch nicht so_ feels more natural.

Answer (score 5):

"Sei nicht so" means "don't be like that". You can say this in situation where it is clear which behavior you mean with "that". "So" refers to a specific kind of behavior which you can see just in the moment when you say that.

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. The [help] will answer any remaining questions on how it works.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for

> Sei doch nicht so! (informal)
>
> Seien Sie doch nicht so! (formal)

Both valid, however the problem these expressions have is every German speaker expects an adverb describing the behaviour frowned upon. It's a bit too uncertain what is meant to German ears.

The other problem is *Sei doch nicht so* is an old-fashioned chat-up phrase.

> Willste nicht tanzen? – Nö. – Komm, sei doch nicht so.

*Don't wanna dance? – Nah. – Come on, "don't be like that".*

Used in many German (and German translations of) teenie films of the 1960ies through 1980ies. Call it conditioning but everytime I hear *sei doch nicht so* I immediately think someone is trying to hit on me.

Comment: ‘Every German speaker expects an adverb describing the behaviour frowned upon’ — really? number 1 for *adverb;* I think you wanted to say (predicative) adjective. Really? number 2 for the expectation: I do not. ‘Nun sei doch nicht so!’, is an entirely complete sentence with nothing missing. And it may be because I’m male or young or both, both I wouldn’t be hearing a chat-up phrase in it either.

Comment: I am male, but can certainly see the persuasion in it, in both languages. Maybe if you try to think of your parents or boss saying it to you? :-)